# react native vertical auto slide animation (infinite)?

Tags: react-native, react-animated

Unfortunately I don't know what it's called and I searched a lot but I couldn't find what I'm looking for, suppose I have a list of objects which they have their own content and I need to show them vertically. and  my goal is after some interval last item drop and goes to first with an animation and other items shift down [image] something like this that happen infinite and with transition. can anyone give me some hint or help me how to achieve this?

Comment: I think you are looking for an infinite swiper or an infinite pager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So [react-native-swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper) will give you infinite scrolling out of the box, but for the web, it doesnt do swipes. If you are lucky, then you are developing for android/ios only, if not you can play around with [PanResponder](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder) to add swipe support for the web (I havent done this before so I didnt attempt)

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';
import {
  colorGenerator,
  colorManipulators,
} from '@phantom-factotum/colorutils';

const totalItems = 4;

export default function App() {
  const DATA = colorGenerator(totalItems).map((color, index) => ({
    color,
    textColor: colorManipulators.darkenColor(color, 0.45),
    title: 'Item' + (index + 1),
  }));
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Swiper style={styles.wrapper} showsButtons={true} horizontal={true}>
        {DATA.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <View
              style={[styles.item, { backgroundColor: item.color }]}
              key={item.title}>
              <Text style={[styles.text, { color: item.textColor }]}>
                {item.title}
              </Text>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </Swiper>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  wrapper: {
    // flex: 1,
  },
  item: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

Here's a [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/BMUUJwsuF)

Comment: I worked on the vertical scrolling https://snack.expo.dev/vhde7GuMh