# How to swipe content in React Native

Tags: react-native, swipe

I am new to React Native and I have given a swipe task.

1. Swipe should change only the content of a view not the entire page
2. The swipe action should be tracked in dots bar.

I found two packages which are [React Native Tab View](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view) and [react-page-transitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-page-transitions). I am thinking about manipulating one of them to achieve such action or is there a better way? What is the best practice in swipe?

**First Content**

[image: text]

**Second Content (frist content swiped)**

[image: text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I responded to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73783983/react-native-vertical-auto-slide-animation-infinite/73785593#73785593) and recommended [react-native-swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper) as it has the swiping functionality built in out of the box (this isnt enabled for web):

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';
import {
  colorGenerator,
  colorManipulators,
} from '@phantom-factotum/colorutils';

const totalItems = 4;

export default function App() {
  const DATA = colorGenerator(totalItems).map((color, index) => ({
    color,
    textColor: colorManipulators.darkenColor(color, 0.45),
    title: 'Item' + (index + 1),
  }));
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Swiper style={styles.wrapper} showsButtons={true} horizontal={true}>
        {DATA.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <View
              style={[styles.item, { backgroundColor: item.color }]}
              key={item.title}>
              <Text style={[styles.text, { color: item.textColor }]}>
                {item.title}
              </Text>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </Swiper>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  wrapper: {
    // flex: 1,
  },
  item: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

Here's the [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/BMUUJwsuF)